# Formula to Access Network Folder/Files

Tags: formula, administration

Im trying to access my local folders using custom Formula'Hyperlink' function

[image]

This is my formula Test Open = HYPERLINK("file:///" & Path__c ,"Go To"). When I click the link it gives blank Untitled Page

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. Your path is not specified correctly for a [`file:` URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), which doesn't use Windows-style paths. Your path would be, I believe, `C:/Program%20Files/Sublime%20Text%203/changelog.txt` (see [Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/) docs).
2. Browsers are unlikely to open a `file:///` link from a public web page without additional intervention from you (such as hitting reload or enter on the resulting blank page), as this would be a security risk. I've confirmed that Firefox behaves that way and I believe it's similar in other mainstream browsers.

Comment: Hello, it seems google chrome blocking the link , I tried this on Mozilla and i just need to refresh the page to display the local files/folders